# Emacs IMAP client for Windows

Tags: windows, email, emacs

I've looked at Gnus and WanderLust, but they don't seem to be supported on Windows (which I use at work). What are some Emacs email clients with good support for IMAP that run on Windows as well (without running Cygwin)?

Answer (score 0):

I don't personally use Gnus but according to [this page](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/GnusTutorial) it actually does run on windows without Cygwin.